# Unlimited Private Email Aliases?

Tags: email

I don't know whether this question belongs here but I can't think of any other community that would want or know a service like this the most.

I'm looking for an email provider service that allows me to create and destroy *children* email addresses easily, and to manage and view them all from a single place. It'd behave like a single inbox, aggregating the emails of all addresses.

This would allow me to, for example, sign up to your-service.com with `g063d0442-8eee-427c-8c71-70c27cdd895a@provider.com` and your-newsletter.com with `g40def3e6-6cdf-4191-b163-9fa3ce4997c3@provider.com`. If I find out your-service.com sends unwanted spam or leaked the database, I can just cancel the associated address in a second and no one would be the wiser.

The UX would be somewhat similar to Bitcoin's HD Wallets.

It's also relatively similar to [disposable email addresses](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=disposable+email+addresses) as offered by services like [Mailinator](https://www.mailinator.com/), but private.

I'm aware of `base+alias@provider.com` type aliases, but AFAIK they always expose `base` and `@provider.com`, which is something I'm looking to avoid.

There also seem to exist services such as https://www.33mail.com/ which provide unlimited aliases by offering a subdomain of the provider, so `everything@you.33mail.com` will be aggregated in your inbox, but again, it has the same problem of exposing the parent address.

Comment: Why wouldn't local alias parts work in your case? I.e. "user+auuid@provider.tld"?

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: Look at the RFC for email:) the + sign denotes an alias. Works like a charm. A catchall domain works well as well.

Comment: So you’re exposing your main address with every alias. Aliases work well for testing purposes but not for security.

Comment: That’s just not true and this discussion is nothing for the comments.

Comment: @lautaro.dragan I'm facing the same question now. What did you end up using?

Comment: Hushmail has a free trial and it’s pretty decent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Church of the Swimming Elephant](https://www.cotse.net/)

Seriously!

It's a security site that provides various privacy services to include exactly what you appear to be asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Hushmail](https://www.hushmail.com/) seems to be an option, although I haven't tried it.